# How to execute a command in a different shell?

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I have a bash script that opens up a shell called salome shell and it should execute a command called as_run in that shell. The thing is that after entering the salome shell it doesn't execute the command until I exit the salome shell. This is the code that i got:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /opt/salome/appli_V2018.0.1_public
./salome shell
eval "as_run /home/students/gbroilo/Desktop/Script/Template_1_2/exportSalome"
```

What should I do in order to execute the command in the salome shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be this is what you want:

```
# call salome shell with commands in a specified script file
cd /opt/salome/appli_V2018.0.1_public
./salome shell <"/home/students/gbroilo/Desktop/Script/Template_1_2/exportSalome"
```

Or might be this is what you want:

```
# pipe a command as_run... to salome shell
cd /opt/salome/appli_V2018.0.1_public
echo "as_run /home/students/gbroilo/Desktop/Script/Template_1_2/exportSalome" | ./salome shell
```

Anyway, you have to read the salome guide about how salome shell call it's script.

Answer (score 1):

Most shells implement a way to pass the commands as parameters, e.g.

```
dash -c 'x=1 ; echo $x'
```

You'll need to consult your shell's manual to see if it's possible.

You can also try sending the commands to the standard input of the shell:

```
echo 'set x = 1 ; echo $x' | tcsh
```

Using a HERE doc might be a bit more readable in case of complex commands:

```
tcsh << 'TCSH'
    set x = 1
    echo $x
TCSH
```

Comment: I tried both solutions but they don't wotk... it opens up the shell but it doesnt execute anything

Comment: sadly there is not much around regarding the salome shell and how to pass arguments

Comment: Maybe this? http://trac.lecad.si/vaje/chrome/site/doc8.3.0/gui/KERNEL/salome_command.html